# SIFT feature matching performance while matching multiple images

Tags: sift, kdtree, knn

I have a image library, with has ~5000 images with ~150 features. Now I have another image with ~300 features, and I want to find 5 most similar images in my library.

The brute force need about 300 * 5000 * 150 * 128 operations, costs too much time. So I built a kd-tree for features in each image in my library, which means ~5000 kd-trees. I used [bbf search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_bin_first) for approximate nearest neighbors like other sift libraries did. But the performance became even slower than my brute force algorithm. To make sure that its not my implementation's fault, I modified other libraries's matching algorithm to brute force, and their performance increased too.

My question is that is there any possible to combine ~5000 kd-trees into one tree? Or is there some other way to increase performance while matching multiple images?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by making a kd-tree for each image's features. Don't the features for each image form a 150-dimensional vector? You should be inserting the vectors in a kdtree to do the search. But 150-dimensional search in a kdtree may not be much better than brute force.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using [Locality Sensitive Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing), which should be considerably faster,  if not 100% accurate.